# Python Requests .iter_content() generator to binary data?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using the Python requests API to stream data over HTTP and need to decode the binary data properly. Each block of data starts with a one byte header ('H', 'N', or 'S') and the blocks contain variable length strings (among other things). The data is gzip compressed so I want to use .iter_content which automatically decompresses the data (as opposed to .raw), and do want to iterate on the data to detect each 1-byte header. But within the body of each block I need to grab a few bytes and operate on it. Problem is, it's not clear how I would do that since .iter_content() is a generator and I'm not familiar with how I could convert or extract the data out of it. Here's a stripped down block of code that illustrates what I want to accomplish:

```
    resp = self.session.post(myurl, data=payload, stream=True, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})

    if resp.status_code == 200:
        for byte in resp.iter_content(1):
            if byte == 'H':
                print "INFO: Heartbeat"
                body = resp.iter_content(9)
                print body # THIS DOESN'T WORK SINCE .iter_content IS A GENERATOR
            elif byte == 'N':
                print "INFO: Snapshot"
                len = resp.iter_content(2)
                mystr = resp.iter_content(len)
                print mystr # ALSO DOESN'T WORK FOR THE SAME REASON
            elif byte == 'S':
                print "INFO: Streaming"
            else:
                break
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really really want to use `iter_content` you will need to buffer the data somewhere. You might find it easier just to use `Response.raw`, because despite what your original question states it absolutely can uncompress the data:

```
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
data = r.raw.read(decode_content=True)
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. Unfortunately raw.read() isn't really documented. I'll have to peek into the source code. Now I just need to know how best to convert this binary data into the different formats they represent (two's complement ints of various sizes, single and double precision floats, etc)

Comment: The key thing to know about `raw.read()` is that it's actually a [urllib3 HTTPResponse object](http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/helpers.html#urllib3.response.HTTPResponse).

As for your conversion issues, you'll want to take a look at the standard library's [struct](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module.

Comment: @Lukasa Does `raw.read()` avoid reading all the content into memory?